# Determine what the rotation axis is given a rotation matrix

Tags: joint

How do I find out around which axis the coordinate system has to rotate, if the rotation matrix is given?

$ {^{a}R_{b} } $ = $ \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{matrix}\right)$

$ {^{a}R_{c} } $ = $ \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\\end{matrix}\right)$

For $ {^{a}R_{b} } $ I thought, that it has to be a rotation around the z-axis, because 
$R(z,\theta) =  \left(\begin{matrix} cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) & 0 \\ sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{matrix}\right)$

the values at the positions $a_{13}, a_{23},a_{33},a_{32},a_{31}$ of $ {^{a}R_{b} } $ and $R(z,\theta)$ are identical.

So I solved $cos(\theta) = 0$ =>$\theta = 90° $ => 90° rotation around z-axis.

But how do I solve it, if there is more than 1 rotation, like for $ {^{a}R_{c} } $?

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155078/closed-form-for-eigenvectors-of-rotation-matrix).

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wikipedia article on conversion between the rotation matrix and Euler axis/angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix_.E2.86.94_Euler_axis.2Fangle):

Given a rotation matrix:
$$
\
R 
= \begin{bmatrix}    
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13}\\
r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23}\\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
$$

You can get the rotation angle:
$$
\theta = \cos^{-1} \left[ 0.5(r_{11} +r_{22} + r_{33} - 1) \right] \\
n_x = \frac{r_{32} - r_{23}}{2 \sin(\theta)} \\
n_y = \frac{r_{13} - r_{31}}{2 \sin(\theta)} \\
n_z = \frac{r_{21} - r_{12}}{2 \sin(\theta)} \\
$$

So, given your first problem:
$$
R 
= \begin{bmatrix}    
0 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\
$$

$$
\theta = \cos^{-1} \left[ 0.5(0 +0 +1 - 1) \right] \\
\theta = 1.57 \mbox{rad} = 90^{\circ} \\
n_x = \frac{0 - 0}{2 \sin(90^{\circ})} \\
n_y = \frac{0 - 0}{2 \sin(90^{\circ})} \\
n_z = \frac{-1 - 1}{2 \sin(90^{\circ})} \\
n_x = 0 \\
n_y = 0 \\
n_z = -1 \\
$$
So you can see here that, for your first problem, you rotate 90 degrees about the -z axis, or equivalently, you rotate -90 degrees about the +z axis.

Similarly, for your second problem:
$$
R 
= \begin{bmatrix}    
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\\
$$

$$
\theta = \cos^{-1} \left[ 0.5(0 +0 + 0 - 1) \right] \\
\theta = 2.09\mbox{rad} = 120^{\circ} \\
n_x = \frac{1 - 0}{2 \sin(120^{\circ})} \\
n_y = \frac{1 - 0}{2 \sin(120^{\circ})} \\
n_z = \frac{1 - 0}{2 \sin(120^{\circ})} \\
n_x = 0.577 \\
n_y = 0.577 \\
n_z = 0.577 \\
$$

Here you have an axis of rotation that is x=y=z=0.577 (but could be scaled to, say, x=y=z=1, just for thinking about the nature of the rotation), and then you rotate +120 degrees about that axis.

Hope this helps; please comment if I've left something unclear.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the product of rotation matrices are not unique.

> Any orientation can be achieved by composing three elemental rotations.[1](http://personal.maths.surrey.ac.uk/st/T.Bridges/SLOSH/3-2-1-Eulerangles.pdf)

To recover a set of rotation angles you'll need to start with the full rotation matrix and then work backwards. Let's look at a 3-2-1 rotation.

$ {R_{321} } $ = $ \left(\begin{matrix} 
cos\theta cos\phi & cos\theta sin\psi & -sin\theta \\ 
sin\phi sinθcosψ−cos\phi sinψ & sin\phi sinθsinψ+ cos\phi cosψ & sin\phi cosθ \\ 
cos\phi sinθcosψ+ sin\phi sinψ & cos\phi sinθsinψ−sin\phi cosψ & cos\phi cosθ \\
\end{matrix}\right)$

We can now solve for $\theta$. This can be used to solve for $\psi$ and $\phi$. Looking at your $^aR_c$ matrix, we can find the $\theta$ is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\psi$ is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $\phi$ is 0.

__

[More on recovering euler rotations](http://personal.maths.surrey.ac.uk/st/T.Bridges/SLOSH/3-2-1-Eulerangles.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

For solving individual cases, if you do not want to script yourself, you can enter the matrix in this [Online Calculator for 3D Rotation Formats](http://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/), switch the output to degrees, and see the axis-angle output.

In case your of ${}^aR_c$, it outputs a 120 degrees rotation around the axis [0.5773503, 0.5773503, 0.5773503].

Answer (score 0):

Consider an arbitrary rotation matrix $\bf R$ $\in$ SO(3).  We can use it transform a vector $v \in {\mathbb R}^3$ by $$ w = {\bf R}v$$
Intuitively, if $v$ corresponds to the rotation axis of $\bf  R$ then it will be unchanged by the rotation, that is, $w = v$.

So the rotation axis must be an eigenvector of $\bf R$.  Since $\bf R$ is  a 3x3 matrix it has 3 eigenvectors.  Each eigenvector has an associated eigenvalue: there is always at least one eigenvalue equal to 1 (ie. the vector's length is unchanged by the rotation), and for non-zero rotation the other two eigenvalues are a complex conjugate pair.  The eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue equal to one is the rotation axis.

A simple example in MATLAB

```
>> R = roty(0.3)
R =
    0.9553         0    0.2955
         0    1.0000         0
   -0.2955         0    0.9553
```

which is a rotation of 0.3 radians about the y-axis (this function is from my Robotics Toolbox for MATLAB).

```
>> [x,e] = eig(R)

x =

   0.7071 + 0.0000i   0.7071 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.7071i   0.0000 - 0.7071i   0.0000 + 0.0000i

e =

   0.9553 + 0.2955i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.9553 - 0.2955i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
```

where `x` is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors, and `e` is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.  The unit eigenvalue is in column 3 so our rotation axis is the third column of `x` which is real and equal to $[0, 1, 0]^T$ which is a unit-vector parallel to the y-axis — the original axis of rotation.

The complex eigenvalues tell you about the amount of rotation around the axis

```
>> angle(e(1,1))
ans =
    0.3000
```

The Toolbox has a function which does all this for you

```
>> [theta,v] = tr2angvec(R)

theta =
    0.3000

v =
         0    1.0000         0
```

To go in the opposite direction, from a rotation axis and angle, to a rotation matrix use Rodrigues' formula.  This is provided in the Toolbox as

```
>> angvec2r(theta,v)
ans =
    0.9553         0    0.2955
         0    1.0000         0
   -0.2955         0    0.9553
```